# Como puedo encontrar un elemento checkbox WebDriver java?

Tags: java, selenium, test-ng

Necesito encontrar y seleccionar un checkbox.

```
<p class="checkbox">
  <div class="checker" id="uniform-cgv">
    <span class="checked">
      <input name="cgv" id="cgv" value="1" type="checkbox">
    </span>
  </div>
  <label for="cgv"></label>
  <a href="http://ejemplo.phpo  
  id_cms=3&amp;controller=cms&amp;content_only=1" class="iframe" rel="nofollow">
  (Read the Terms of Service)</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Es preferido de incorporar tu código en tu respuesta con copiar y pegar, formateandolo con `CTRL-K`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que preguntas, lo puedes lograr utilizando el método findElement de el webdriver.

El findElement se puede utilizar para varias cosas, desde realizar acciones sobre un botón o un formulario hasta para obtener la parte de html contenida en la etiqueta.

Realizar operaciones sobre el checkbox, debería ser algo similar a :

```
    WebElement checkboxField = driver.findElement(By.id("uniform-cgv"));
    checkboxField .click();
```

Si esto no funciona, la documentación también permite buscar por otros atribudos además del ID.

Aquí encontrarás toda la documentación: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp